# Javascript toSource then toObject

Tags: javascript, string, object

when toSource method is used to an object ..it will be like this

```
({name:"myname", value:"myvalue"})
```

my question is how would you convert it back to object? or rather just access the properties like

```
alert(objectName.name);
```

thus alerting "myname"

Answer (score 3):

Use `eval` to change it back to an object. `alert(eval({name:"myname"}.toSource()).name)`.

Comment: Stripping the parenthesis off will not work with eval. Not stripping them will. Source: willcode4beer.com/tips.jsp?set=jsonInvalidLabel

Answer (score 3):

`toSource()` returns a string, so you can use javascript's `.replace()` method, passing it a regular expression to strip off the parentheses, and then call `JSON.parse()` on the resultant string to turn it back into an object.

Like so:

```
 var obj = {name: "myname", value:"myvalue"};
 var toSourced = obj.toSource();
 var stringObj = toSourced.replace(/\((.*)\)/, "$1");
 var objAgain = JSON.parse(stringObj);
 alert(objAgain.name);
```

As a side note, `toSource()` is not supported by IE or Chrome, and you should avoid it's use as you can turn a JSON object into a string by passing it to `JSON.stringify()`, which is native in IE8+, Firefox, and Chrome.

Comment: uhh ... what if one of the string values of the object had parentheses in it?

Comment: That's why I did not make the `.*` non-greedy. It's intentionally greedy so that it will skip over as many `)` in the main json string as possible, and will almost always stop at the last one unless someone has crazy-formed json.

Comment: The string returned by `toSource` is not valid JSON (even with the parentheses stripped off) because it doesn't put the property names in quotes. Some object types (like `Date` and `Number`) are also serialized in non-JSON-compatible ways. `eval` should work in most cases.

Comment: Stripping the parenthesis off will not work with eval. Not stripping them will. Source: http://willcode4beer.com/tips.jsp?set=jsonInvalidLabel